# SVN client for Mac

Tags: applications, software-recommendation

I cannot seem to find any good Subversion client for my Mac! I use TortoiseSVN at work, and it's awesome, but it's for Windows only. My colleague uses Cornerstone for his Mac, and it is not bad and has a good interface, but it does cost money.

I could stick with Terminal, but a GUI makes it easier when a lot of merging is needed.

So, any suggestions?

p.s. I like sleek graphical interfaces, my philosophy is this: if the app doesn't look good, stick with Terminal.

Comment: I'm closing this to new answers. If someone wants to edit this to "describe the problem more clearly" we could open it. It would be better to ask how to do something specific rather than just asking for "hey - what's your favorite SVN client - the list at wikipedia isn't complete enough"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode has a built-in SVN client which is merely okay. Some people seem to like SvnX, but I've not been happy with its user interface.

But here's a different idea: unless you have some specific reason to stick with SVN and ONLY SVN, you could try Git. Git comes with a few GUI tools (which are invoked from the command line), and you can continuously integrate between Git and SVN repositories with very little effort. The Git branching model is also especially fantastic for collaboration, although even for single-person projects I like it much more than SVN, as it gives me a lot more flexibility in how I manage and release my projects. There are also a number of fantastic GUIs for Git on OS X, many of them free, and I believe Xcode supports git directly now, too.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes I saw few tools for git and I liked them. But I have been using svn at work and home for both business and personal projects. And I don't like idea of integrating back and forth. Definitely something to consider in any case. thanks!

Comment: git-svn makes the continuous integration really easy. Just think of the svn repo as the place that you push to! (Because that's what git-svn does.)

Answer (score 2):

[Source Tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) is a good free app for SVN, Git and Mercurial. Support is great and it as good look!

Comment: Source Tree is pretty good, I've been using it for some Git projects, but it doesn't do SVN **natively**, it only does so through Git or Mercurial compatibility layers, which may or may not be an issue in this case.

Answer (score 1):

[svnX](http://code.google.com/p/svnx/) is an graphical client to [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) (svn) for Mac OS X.

Not the most pretty client but svnX is open source and has been actively supported for many years.

[image: Screen shot of svnX 1.3 for Mac OS X]

Comment: yes it is ugly as... :)

Answer (score 0):

There is also [uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com) - I haven't tried it myself, I use SVN via the Eclipse IDE and/or the command line, so I can't comment on it's quality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [CRAX](http://www.ewas.pl/crax/) and I'm finding this software good enough in SVN local repo management. Using it is very similiar to the using TortoiseSVN and TotalCommander on Windows. And this soft is cheeper than other SVN clients for MAC.

Comment: Thanks for the answers on this. Be sure to read the [promotion section](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) on [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) if you recommend the same software several times.

Answer (score -1):

i know its a bit old but if you dont want any client you can just right click on finder and connect to server input your url and username and password and you can view all the files and folder

Comment: How would this work for Subversion, including checkin/checkout etc.?

Comment: to do the checkout you will have to use terminal for the operations. but the solution i gave was only for quick view. And xcode pretty good for the file comparing feature

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the terminal (terminal.app) for small operations.

Type "svn help" to find out how to use the svn with the promp. ;)

Comment: The Op says he knows this but does not want to do this.